# How to setup EC2 internal IP forwarding to External DNS using macos X?

Tags: macos, amazon-ec2, ip, portforwarding, ipfw

Here the problem, I have two servers on EC2, which have internal/private IPs (10.148.73.230, 10.148.73.231), unfortunately I do not have Elastic IPs available and connect to these servers using External DNS like: ec2-50-132-69-161.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (IP:50.132.69.161) and ec2-50-132-69-162.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (IP:50.132.69.162).

I have macbook and now I need to simulate access to these EC2 servers using their internal IPs.

The first idea was to setup IP forwarding on mac using: **ipfw** and **natd**... but after several hours it still not working for some reason. Im fine to make quick and dirty, or using any GUI, but didn't find any...

Desperate for help, here my current script:

```
sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
ipfw add 1000 forward 10.148.73.230,80 log ip from me 80 to 50.132.69.162) dst-port 80
/usr/sbin/natd -alias_address 10.148.73.230 -interface en1 -use_sockets -same_ports -unregistered_only -dynamic -clamp_mss -enable_natportmap -natportmap_interface en0 -redirect_port tcp 50.132.69.162:1-10000 1-10000 -l
```

Or is there any better solution to make the forwarding?

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a shot in the dark here as as windows/linux guy.  I do understand your problem with EC2 and use it myself, generally with elastic ip's however.

Is it possible to just setup the hosts file like you could on windows/linux??
http://support.apple.com/kb/TA27291?viewlocale=en_US